# How would I convert this to a for loop?

Tags: java

The user would need to enter a number for the meter reading, a try catch block will initialize if the user enters anything other than a number and an error message pops out if the user has a negative number, doing this in do-while would be simple but I am stumped on how this would be a for-loop

```
    public static int readStartReading(){ 
    int reading = 0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean problemFlag = false;
    do {
        problemFlag = false;
        try {
            System.out.print("Enter the meter reading at the beginning of the year: ");
            String input = keyboard.nextLine();
            reading = Integer.parseInt(input);// 7. Assign a value to reading through the input device
        } catch (NumberFormatException x){
            problemFlag = true;
            System.out.println("You have to enter a number.");
        } if (reading < 0){
            System.out.println("The beginning meter reading cannot be negative."); }
    } while (reading < 0 || problemFlag);
    return reading;
}
```

I have noticed my mistake. Thank you for the responses

Comment: *Why* do you want to convert it to a `for` loop?

Comment: I'm wondering the same. It looks like do-while is the best way to achieve what you're trying to do with a loop, is there a specific reason you need a for loop?

Comment: I was going to see if there are any other ways to have it loop, other than a do while loop but looking at it now I'm sure it doesn't need to be. Thank you for the responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it to a for loop very simply but it will not be any difference.
In your case a do-while is better suited.

```
public static int readStartReading(){ 
int reading = 0;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean problemFlag = false;
for(;reading < 0 || problemFlag;)
{
    problemFlag = false;
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter the meter reading at the beginning of the year: ");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        reading = Integer.parseInt(input);// 7. Assign a value to reading through the input device
    } catch (NumberFormatException x){
        problemFlag = true;
        System.out.println("You have to enter a number.");
    } if (reading < 0){
        System.out.println("The beginning meter reading cannot be negative."); }
}
return reading;
}
```

There are also couple small issues

- you don't need the problemFlag
- you are doing the initial reading twice, (user will have to input value twice)

I would rewrite it like so:

```
public static int readStartReading()
{ 
int reading = 0;
Scanner keyboard; //remove first reading here

do
{
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter the meter reading at the beginning of the year: ");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        reading = Integer.parseInt(input);// 7. Assign a value to reading through the input device

        //if control reaches here, you have a valid integer, test it
        if (reading < 0)
            System.out.println("The beginning meter reading cannot be negative.");

    } catch (NumberFormatException x){
        reading = -1; //set reading to a negative invalid value
        System.out.println("You have to enter a number.");
    }
} while(reading < 0)
return reading;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
public static int readStartReading()
{ 
int reading = -1; 
Scanner keyboard; //remove first reading here

while(1)
{
    try 
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the meter reading at the beginning of the year: ");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        reading = Integer.parseInt(input);// 7. Assign a value to reading through the input device

        //if control reaches here, you have a valid integer, test it
        if (reading >= 0)
            break;
        else
            System.out.println("The beginning meter reading cannot be negative.");
    } 
    catch (NumberFormatException x)
        System.out.println("You have to enter a number.");
} 
return reading;
```

}

Comment: I think this is the cleanest solution removes the -1 "hack"/hardcoding. Cheers